# How to periodically update live tile locally on Windows 10

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, live-tile

I didn't find a suitable [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-periodic-notification-overview) to update periodically a tile from the application and not a server. The documentation said that you can update an application tile periodically, but you need to give a URI as the first parameter.

I want to display on the tile information about some items in the application, like the Photos application (but I think Microsoft uses a server for that).

Did someone come with a solution for that?

Thanks.

Comment: This link should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/update-a-live-tile-from-a-background-task

Comment: @KenTucker, I have another question. How can you get the application data found in a database? Should I create a library for database management?

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: You should also create a new question for this

Comment: I'll create a new question. Thank you.